# Can I create a collapsible that shows some of its content before expanding itself?

Tags: javascript

As I said in the title I need the collapsible to show its content up to a certain point even before expanded and then show it fully after expanded. Here's 2 drawings as examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4CHh.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlye6.png

Comment: Please edit your question to prodive the relevant information in relation to your question. Thank you. Maybe this [**W3schools read more Example**](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp) will be of some use to you

Comment: mouse hover you can use

Comment: @NewToJS thank you! that was it, i cant find the way to chose your answer as the correct one, must be cause of sleep deprevation.

Answer (score 0):

Set for line number change `-webkit-line-clamp`

```js
let showbutton = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
for(let i=0; i < showbutton.length; i++) {
showbutton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    items[i].classList.toggle("toggle");
})
  }
```

```css
container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
}

container div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.card{
  width:50%;
  height:max-content;
  border:2px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
}

.card span{
  text-align:left;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.card.toggle span{
  -webkit-line-clamp: unset;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div>
<p class="card"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum finibus dolor quis pellentesque. Phasellus tincidunt elit et tellus auctor tincidunt. Fusce luctus quam ut dolor semper, in mattis orci varius. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi et lectus a nisl sodales dignissim. Suspendisse ornare eget nulla a porta. Donec at nisl eleifend, ultricies turpis rhoncus, vestibulum lacus. Proin nec erat erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod, lacus eget consectetur finibus, sem dui eleifend magna, ut accumsan velit nulla nec mi. Curabitur dictum sagittis massa a condimentum. Aenean egestas turpis ut dolor convallis aliquam. Donec rhoncus enim sit amet odio molestie, porttitor tempus risus viverra.</span>
  <button>READ MORE</button></p>
  </container>
```